# Batch processing not available in Graphical Modeller QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm currently running QGIS 3.6. I'm trying to set up a model that uses the GDAL 'Clip Raster by Mask' tool to extract individual rasters from a DEM. I'm using geopackage polygons as the mask layer. I have no issues carrying out a batch processing when outside of the graphical modeller.

I can't see any option to select 'batch processing' in the graphical modeller tool interface. 
[image: GDAL Extract by Mask interface within graphical modeller]

Is there a way to carry out batch processing within the graphical modeller?

Comment: I think what you need is a processing script that will use that algorithm. The model is designed to define workflows and then the batch is run outside.

Comment: This is an older question, but were you looking to create one raster file for every polygon in a layer? If so, this is entirely possible in the modeler without batch processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The processing algorithms in the graphical modeler are not exact copies of the tools outside the modeler. One of the differences, as you discovered, is the absence of batch processing.

To "batch process" in the modeler, you have to add the algorithm to the model multiple times. Unfortunately there's no way to `copy/paste` or `duplicate` an algorithm, so you have to enter all the parameters again.

The processing modeler is not perfect.

Comment: Not sure if this was valid for older versions, but in current versions (e.g. QGIS 3.34), you can copy/past algorithms in the model. Of course, you then have to manually change settings.